# Let $p, q, r$ be distinct primes and let $n=p+q+r$. Show that $S_n$ contains a subgroup of order $pqr$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let $p, q, r$ be distinct primes and let $n=p+q+r$. Show that $S_n$ contains a subgroup of order $pqr$.

I'm not sure how to start this, thanks!

Comment: You can prove a stronger version, there's no need for $p, q$, and $r$ to be prime or even distinct. Try with $S_6$: Can you think of a "natural" way to find a subgroup of order $2\cdot2\cdot2$?

Comment: Look at the element $(1\  2\  3\  \ldots p)(p+1\  p+2 \ \ldots p+q)(p+q+1\  p+q+2\ \ldots p+q+r)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

1. $S_p$ contains a subgroup of order $p$.
2. $S_p\times S_q$ is a subgroup of $S_{p+q}$.

*Note*: As @pjs36 mentioned, there's no need for $p,q,r$ being prime. The extra you got from that hypothesis is the subgroup you find is *cyclic*.

Comment: Are #1 and #2 known theorems? Or how do we know those properties?

Comment: They are too simple for a theorem. As for why they are true, please refer to Prahlad's comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the cyclic subgroup generated by the product of a $p$-cycle, a $q$-cycle, and a $r$-cycle, each disjoint with one another. What would the order of such an element, and the subgroup generated by it, be equal to?